# Need a regex javascript to read every line check for a particular string and display the whole line if there is a match

Tags: javascript

I uses this code to paste from the clipboard so that I filtered some conditions using regex.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <textarea id="mytextarea" cols="150" rows="35" ></textarea>

    <script>
        var txtArea = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
        txtArea.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
        pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
        var newData = pastedData.replace(/([\d]{2}\/[\d]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\s[\d]{2}:[\d]   {2}:[\d]{2})|([A-Z]{5}\d{2})/g, '');
        txtArea.value = txtArea.value + newData;
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now what I want is if I paste something like this in the text area-

```
"Total Excess Charges are £ 351.52........ excluding vat.
Survey Charge £250.79
Breakdown of charges items :-
 COST=£0351.52
LSDXW08 01/07/2016 10:30:00"
```

I want to display the lines only if the line has the match of "£" and remove the regex pattern with time format. I was able to remove the regex format on paste but not able to get the lines with the "£" match.

I want the the output to be something like this(showing the lines if it has the symbol match -

```
 "Total Excess Charges are £ 351.52........ excluding vat.
        Survey Charge £250.79
        COST=£0351.52"
```

I am able to remove only the regex pattern which I used in the code. Can something be done for this? Using event trigger after pasting the content and later showing the required lines in seperate section of the page as output is also welcome.

Comment: Please can you provide the output that you'd like to see?

Comment: If I paste the above three lines, I must be able to see these two lines as in - "Total Excess Charges are £ 351.52........ excluding vat.
Survey Charge £250.79"

Comment: So essentially you want to take a string with many lines, and return only lines that include the "£" symbol?

Comment: Yes exactly! I am unable to extend my code to perform this.- @atkinchris

Answer (score 1):

If you can also use array functions you can get the lines like this

```
let text = `Total Excess Charges are £ 351.52........ excluding vat.
Survey Charge £250.79
Breakdown of charges items :-`
let searchFor = '£';
let lines = text.split('\n').filter( line => line.indexOf(searchFor) !== -1)
//lines ["Total Excess Charges are £ 351.52........ excluding vat.", "Survey Charge £250.79"]
```

Comment: additionally use trim to remove unwanted spaces.

Comment: I am not able to come up with this. Can you include it in my code above and post back please

Comment: @swaroopreddy you mean you cannot make it run?

Comment: I meant I cant make it run integreting in my code. - @eltonkamami

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
    <body>
    <textarea id="mytextarea" cols="150" rows="35" ></textarea>

    <script>
        var txtArea = document.getElementById('mytextarea');
        txtArea.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
        pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
        var newData = pastedData.replace(/([\d]{2}\/[\d]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\s[\d]{2}:[\d]   {2}:[\d]{2})|([A-Z]{5}\d{2})/g, '');
             var lines = newData.split('\n');
             for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++) {
             var newline = lines[i].toString();         
             if(newline.indexOf('£') !== -1) {
             finalData += newline + "\n";
        }
    }

    txtArea.value = finalData;
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: All I missed is inserting a meta tag for character encoding. Lesson learnt.